# Fetch Api in react js with axios

Tags: reactjs

I am using axios to fetch data but fetch data is showing in one row only but want to display more than 1 console image red mark getting this API

[image: Console.image]

But when I write `Postdata(prevArray => [...prevArray, response.data])` this code all row show the data but when I `setInterval` use then in image

[image: Gui Infinity page]

I want that API I fetch

[image: Display like this image]

```
const [setdata, fetchdata] = useState([]);
const [setpostData, Postdata] = useState([]);


  useEffect(() => {
    getfetchData();
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    // Object.values(setdata).map((val) => {
    //   getPostData(val.Player, val.IP, val.Port, val.ChannelName);
    // });
    setdata.forEach(function (val) {
      getPostData(val.Player, val.IP, val.Port, val.ChannelName);
      // setInterval(() => {
      //    getPostData(val.Player, val.IP, val.Port, val.ChannelName);
      // }, 500);
    });
  }, [setdata]);

  function getfetchData() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:9763/api/getPlayers",
      {
        headers: {
          "accepts": "application/json",
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        },
        auth: {
          username: 'admin',
          password: 'password'
        },

      }).then(response => {
        //console.log(response.data)
        console.log([...Object.values(response.data).flat()]);
        fetchdata([...Object.values(response.data).flat()]);
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  function getPostData(Player, IP, Port, channelName) {
    //console.log("insideFunction Row1"+Player);
    var data = {
      PlayerName: Player,
      ChannelName: channelName,
      Port: Port,
      IpAddress: IP
    }
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'http://localhost:9763/api/getPlayerStatus',
      data,
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      auth: {
        username: 'admin',
        password: 'password'
      }
    }).then(response => {
     
    //  Postdata([response.data]);
      Postdata(prevArray => [...prevArray, response.data])
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log("Error In Post Data", error);
    });
  }
  console.log(setpostData);
```

Comment: Perhaps this article will help: https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/

Comment: just spread `response.data` : `Postdata(prevArray => [...prevArray, ...response.data])`

Comment: thx for the reply,  but i try this it shows me value in table row but when I run setInterval to show running time it does not work properly previous one's row's not clear and  showing me (upper second position images in question)

Comment: useEffect(() => {
    setdata.forEach(function (val) {
      getPostData(val.Player, val.IP, val.Port, val.ChannelName);
 setInterval(() => {
    getPostData(val.Player, val.IP, val.Port, val.ChannelName);
  }, 500);
    });

  }, [setdata]);
 Using this code to run interval